# writing views style plugin -error - Display "Master" has an invalid style plugin

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm writing a views display plguin, I defined it as follows in mymodule.views.inc

```
function mymodule_views_plugins() {
  $plugins['style']['mymodule_articles_list'] = array(
    'title' => t('mymodule Articles Listing'),
    'help' => t('Display Articles using citation'),
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule'),
    'handler' => 'mymodule_articles_list_style_plugin',
    'uses row plugin' => TRUE,
    'uses options' => TRUE,
    'uses grouping' => FALSE,
    'type' => 'normal',
    'use pager' => FALSE,
    'use ajax' => FALSE,
    'theme' => 'mymodule_articles_list'
  );
  return $plugins;
}
```

I created class and theme functions. When I select 'mymodule Articles Listing' while created view I get error

> Display "Master" has an invalid style plugin. Display "Page" has an
>   invalid style plugin.

**Upate 1**

While running in devel execute php

```
$style_plugin = views_get_plugin('style','mumodule_articles_list');
```

does not return any thing, which means there is something wrong with definition

Answer (score 1):

The first error is returned from [views_plugin_display::validate()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/views_plugin_display%3a%3avalidate/7), which executes the following code.

```
$style = $this->get_plugin();
if (empty($style)) {
  $errors[] = t('Display "@display" has an invalid style plugin.', array('@display' => $this->display->display_title));
}
```

The code that [views_plugin_display::get_plugin()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/views_plugin_display%3a%3aget_plugin/7) executes when it is called without arguments is practically the following one.

```
$name = $this->get_option('style_plugin');
$plugin = views_get_plugin('style', $name);

if (!$plugin) {
  return;
}
```

That code fails when [views_get_plugin()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/views_get_plugin/7) doesn't find the plugin definition for `$name`, which could happen when it doesn't find the file containing the handler, or the name returned from [views_plugin_display::get_option()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/views_plugin_display%3a%3aget_option/7) is wrong.

Comment: file name of handler is same as handler name.inc and is in the root folder of module.

Comment: oops, I did not added handler.inc in mymodule.info file.

Comment: Did you implement [hook_views_api()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7)?